# Actions On Google V2 Node.js - Attempting to use conversation.data but it does not work as expected

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am following the documentation provided by Google in trying to get the  `convseration.data` JSON object to store some data I need to be used in later intents.

[Save Data in Conversation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data)

Currently in my project, I have one intent that grabs a parameter stored by an action and attempts to save it in `conv.data`. In this intent, it is done the following code:

```
[INTENTS.INTENT_A]: (conv, { parameter }) => {
    conv.data.tempvariable = parameter;
}
```

In a later intent, I am trying to access the same tempvariable value by using the following code:

```
[INTENTS.INTENT_B]: (conv) => {
        const tempvariable = conv.data.tempvariable; 
}
```

To the best of my knowledge, I am following the documentation and the conv.data object is always undefined in **INTENT_B**. I have tried storing the parameter with userstorage but I feel like that is undesirable. Is there anything I am doing wrong for this not to be working as expected?

Both **Intent_A** and **Intent_B** use different input/output contexts as reference. In V1 of the client library, I was using app.data and it worked just fine, but with the introduction to V2 and the implementation of the conversation object, it suddenly doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: Can you verify that the `parameter` from the first intent is correct?

Comment: @NickFelker I have verified that it is correct, I have cut out a lot of other logic from the intents to make the example simpler, but I use the parameter variable and it contains the value I want. Additionally, I have logged the conv.data object and it contains the data I need while in Intent_A but as soon as that intent is over and moves on to another one, the conv.data object is empty again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I will do it. But first I will make sure that my params are properly declared inside Dialogflow and that I clearly understand the structure of the param itself.
For example, let say I define the following parameters inside Dialogflow:

[image]

In this example, I will solely focus on the `radius` parameter.
After defining radius like so, if a user enters `10 miles` in the input prompt, the radius' structure in the fulfillment will look like so

```
conv.parameters.radius = {
    'amount':10,
    'unit':'mi'
}
```

So If I want to save the radius for a later use, i can do it like this:

```
[INTENTS.INTENT_A]: (conv, params) => {
    conv.data.radius = conv.parameters.radius.amount;
    // or
    conv.data.radius = params['radius']['amount']
}
```

And then to access it later, you can do

```
[INTENTS.INTENT_B]: (conv) => {
    const savedRadius = conv.data.radius; 
    console.log(savedRadius)
}
```

So in my opinion you need to make sure that you clearly understand the structure of the params you are defining inside of Dialogflow, in order to access it inside of your fulfillment.

A good practice... Use tons of `console.log(conv)` for every single intent, to explore and understand the structure of the conversation that is taking place

I hope this helps. Let me know how things worked out for you.